# Web2Py DAL - How to check list:string type items for None

Tags: python, web2py, data-access-layer

I am trying to query a data set to return all list:string items not null.
My example table:

```
db.define_table('newItems',
            Field('name', 'string'),
            Field('tasks', 'list:string'))
```

A query for None like so:

```
for item in db(db.newItems.tasks != None).select(db.newItems.tasks):
```

Returns:

```
[]
[]
[u'Wash Dog', u'Mow Yard']
[]
[u'Do X', u'Then do Y']
[]
```

How do I structure the query so that it only returns:

```
[u'Wash Dog', u'Mow Yard']
[u'Do X', u'Then do Y']
```

Thank you

update:

The answer works when tested on sqlite but it does not work with mongodb. The empty list [] is passed as '' that yields the wrong result:

```
In [4]: db.Tasks.email != []
Out[4]: <Query {'email': {'$ne': ''}}>
```

mongo shell:

```
> db.Tasks.find().count()
1195 (total records)

> db.Tasks.find({'email': {'$ne': ''}}).count()
1195
```

The correct query should be:

```
> db.Tasks.find({email: {$ne: [ ] }}).count()
108
```

Is this is a bug in mongo dal or is there another way I can specify the empty list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you input records via `SQLFORM`, empty values for `task` will get stored as an empty list rather than `None`, so you can do:

```
db(db.newItems.tasks != []).select(db.newItems.tasks)
```

Note, that will also exclude records that happen to have `None` values for `task` (which might exist if you have inserted records without `task` values using `.insert()` instead of a from).

UPDATE: Looks like the above doesn't work with MongoDB due to a bug in the MongoDB adapter.

Comment: thank you for the recommendation. The query still hits on all empty lists using above. Any other suggestions? would a 'having' clause aid in checking for empty?

Comment: Hmm, not when I try it. You might consider posting an app that exhibits the problem on the Google Group so we can see exactly what values you have in your database.

Comment: works for sqlite but not mongodb. I updated question detailing the mongo query that is generated by the DAL.

Comment: Sorry, looks like a bug in the MongoDB adapter. You can submit an issue on [Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/web2py/issues/list).